# Unable to click on Alert with Selenium/Appium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, alert

I have an alert with a OK button that I need to click, but nothing I've tried seems to work on it. My code can identify the alert, but as soon as I try to perform an action it, it seems to interact with the screen behind the alert.

It's a native iOS app that I'm working with. I've tried the following options:

```
1. driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
2. driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss;
3. driver.switchTo().alert();
   driver.findelement(By.id("OK")).click();
4. TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver).tap(xCoordinates, yCoordinates);
    touchAction.perform();
```

Does anyone know of another way to click on this alert?

[image: Alert]

[image: Alert Properties]

[image: OK button properties]

Comment: After re-reading your original post, I see this is a native app.  It's not likely an alert at all, but another page in the app.  Use uiautomator or whatever tool you use for iOS apps (I work with Android) to get the locators like you do with the other elements.

Comment: I've already done that, it doesn't recognise the element by id or xpath. Type is XCUIElementTypeAlert

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the uiautomator properties?  If using xpath, are you specifying "resource-id" instead of "id" ?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the alert, as well as the properties for the alert and for the OK button within the alert

Comment: Try `driver.findelement(By.xpath("//*[@accessibility_id='OK']")).click();`

Comment: That failed with an "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException" error

Answer (score 1):

Add a capability **capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);** in appium your capabilities list! It will allow to accept or OK automatically. My same issue was resolved!

Comment: I tried with the capability added, but it doesn't seem to make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me a synchronizing issue and a simple solution would be to induce [*WebDriverWait*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) with [*ExpectedConditions*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) as [*alertIsPresent()*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#alertIsPresent--) as follows :

- Accept Alert :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()).accept();
  ```
- Dismiss Alert :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()).dismiss();
  ```

---

### Update

As an alternative, you can try the following code block :

```
//import
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
//code block
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

Comment: I tried the wait, but still get the same result. It finds the alert almost immediately, but still interacts with the screen behind the alert.

Comment: Which webdriver variant are you using? Check my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Using IOSDriver, I'm struggling to find the library for Alert

Comment: Updated the answer with the import. let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that code block, but it still gives the same result