# How to handle a blocking page in appium?

Tags: java, appium

I have an issue where a screen that appium inspector cannot locate appears in my app and basically blocks my tests from running since no element can be located. For example, I cannot click on the profile icon on the page. [image]
I have attached a screenshot of the screen.
My question is if there is a way to handle this kind of issue?

Comment: did u checked if the page is in webview, which is not detected by appium inspector.

Comment: How can I check it? And if it is, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the app manually, how do you close this pop-up page?

I've had similar situations when working with Appium, so here's a few suggestions. Whether these work depends on the app and the pop-up page.

First, write code that detects when this happens. A try-catch block in the places where this event usually happens, for example.

Then, to close the blocking page, try one of these:

A) Click the back button.

B) If the elements of the popup are always on the same coordinates, click by coordinates to 'Next' (by using TouchActions). If you use multiple test devices, you might have to write code for each device.

C) Take a look here: [Unable to click on Alert with Selenium/Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256015/unable-to-click-on-alert-with-selenium-appium) . Try `driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss`.

```
void test() {
    try {
        doSomething()
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
        closeBlockingPage()
        doSomething()
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to close it manually I need to click on "Not Now" (which is an option that appears in the screen). This is the issue, that I cannot detect when this screen appears since I don't have a locator for it. To use coordinated is not an option since I am going to use it in device-farm. How can I detect if this screen appears if I cannot locate it? Is there something I can do?

Comment: You cannot detect it with certainty, but you can guess that it appears when you get a NoSuchElementException (because if your test works fine without the blocking page, then this exception means it's highly likely that the blocking page popped up). That's why I suggest a try-catch block.

Comment: Added a new possible solution C.